# AttributeError: type object 'ConfigParser' has no attribute 'Error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, configparser

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

configfile = 'config.ini'

cparser = ConfigParser()
try:
    # assigns values from config
except ConfigParser.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

This code was working a day ago, i dont know if i changed something and it messed things up, but it no longer works

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\k\ping_off-1\v-ups-daemon.py", line 60, in <module>
    except ConfigParser.Error as e:
AttributeError: type object 'ConfigParser' has no attribute 'Error'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.Error) exception is in the base `configparser` module, not in the `configparser.ConfigParser` class. Adjust your code to the following:

```
import configparser as cfg

configfile = 'config.ini'

cparser = cfg.ConfigParser()
try:
    # assigns values from config
except cfg.Error as e:
    print(e)
```